# How to use type that is being defined in a type trait expression?

Tags: c++

So I have this class that defines an `std::optional`:

```cpp
class Token {
    private:
        std::optional<Token> prev;
        std::optional<Token> next;
};
```

This leads to this error because the type that is being defined is used to parameterize `std::optional`: `error: incomplete type 'Token' used in type trait expression`.

What is the right way of defining these members that are `std::optional`s of type of containing class?

Comment: You can't, as you don't know how big the class should be if it contains members of itself. You need to use something that's known, like a pointer or another class.

Comment: I'd separate them into two different classes, depending on what `Token` actually is. But it seems like you could have a `Token` class (without `prev` and `next`) and then a `LinkedTokenList` that just have `prev` and `next`.

Comment: As one of the answers on the duplicate target suggests, you could use `unique_ptr<Token>` instead.